# How to provide meaningful IV for the ECB mode (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography

I want to create ISO 9797 Algorithm3 MAC in Python 3.x at Ubuntu by the following code. I used pyCryptoDome library to provide MAC based on DES3. The code is used from [this](https://bono02.wordpress.com/2015/08/16/des-mac-iso-9797-alg-3-m1-m2-m-is-padding-method/) weblog. It seams ok in algorithm and workflow.

```
import sys
from Crypto.Cipher import DES
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3
from Crypto.Util.strxor import strxor
import binascii


def macIso9797_m2_alg3(key, msg):
    return macIso9797_alg3(key, msg, "80")

def macIso9797_m1_alg3(key, msg):
    return macIso9797_alg3(key, msg, "00")

def macIso9797_alg3(key, msg, pad_start):

    key_len = int(len(key)/2)    

    if (key_len != 16):
        raise ValueError("Key length should be 16 digits")    

    # force header  padding
    msg += pad_start

    # padding with "00"
    lenRestOfData = int((len(msg)/2) % 8)
    msg += "00"*(8-lenRestOfData)

    loopNum = int((len(msg)/2) / 8)

    bufferOutput = binascii.unhexlify("00"*8)
    IV = '\x00'*8    

    keya = binascii.unhexlify(key[0:16])
    keyb = binascii.unhexlify(key[16:])

    print ("\n")

    i = 0
    for i in range (0, loopNum):
        tdesa = DES.new(keya, DES.MODE_ECB, IV)

        data = msg[i*16:i*16+16]        
        print(str(i) + "=" + data)

        x = bufferOutput
        bufferOutput = strxor(binascii.unhexlify(data), bufferOutput)
        print (data + " xor " + binascii.hexlify(x).decode('utf-8').upper() + " = " + binascii.hexlify(bufferOutput).decode('utf-8').upper())

        bufferOutput = tdesa.encrypt(bufferOutput)
        print (" encrypted val = " + binascii.hexlify(bufferOutput).decode('utf-8').upper())

        print ("\n")

    tdesb = DES.new(keyb, DES.MODE_ECB, IV)
    bufferOutput = tdesb.decrypt(bufferOutput)

    print (" decrypted val = " + binascii.hexlify(bufferOutput).decode('utf-8').upper())

    tdesa = DES.new(keya, DES.MODE_ECB, IV)
    bufferOutput = tdesa.encrypt(bufferOutput)

    print (" encrypted val = " + binascii.hexlify(bufferOutput).decode('utf-8').upper())

    return bufferOutput


macKey="EA1302AFBCCF791CB0065BFAD948B092"
message="test message"

print('MAC Key: ' + macKey)
print('MAC: ' + macIso9797_m1_alg3(macKey, message))
```

But I got the following error.

**TypeError: IV is not meaningful for the ECB mode**

How can I prepare appropriate value for IV?

Comment: You've *stringified* your functions. Cryptographic algorithms are defined on bytes, not on hexadecimals. Hexadecimals should only be used whenever a human needs to interpret the bytes (i.e. when you print them out). But the functions themselves should not have any hex / base 64 / whatnot in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ECB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#ECB) mode does not use an IV. So I would argue that the code is either wrong or perhaps taking into account that you might want to change the cipher mode in future and the code has been prepared for it.

But even so, having a static IV of only zeroes is not the best of ideas.

**EDITED**:

There is a version of the `new()` function that doesn't take an IV according to [PyCryptoDome](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/classic.html#ecb-mode).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any appropriate example?

Comment: An example of ECB or an appropriate IV?

Comment: "But even so, having a static IV of only zeroes is not the best of ideas." that depends on the mode and situation.

Comment: @Daniel No! Any example to create MAC based on ISO 9797 Alg3 from a plaintext.

Comment: Please do place additional requests to the answerers of your question.